# PHP Displaying site visits in a line graph VIA Morris.js

Tags: javascript, php, morris.js

I was following this tutorial: [Codediesel](http://www.codediesel.com/visualization/display-line-and-area-charts-in-php-and-mysql/) trying to create a line graph that will show the amount of views per day on a certain page of my website. I have a database set up like:

```
CREATE TABLE `pageviews` ( 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `date` date NOT NULL, 
    `views` bigint(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have data in the table, 3 days, the data looks like the following:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> int(3) 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2015-06-19" 
        ["views"]=> int(49) 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> int(2) 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2015-06-18" 
        ["views"]=> int(103) 
    } 
    [2]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> int(1) 
        ["date"]=> string(10) "2015-06-17" 
        ["views"]=> int(18) 
    } 
}
```

My problem is that the page gives me no Graph, the console produces two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
```

My morris javascript looks like this when rendered by the page:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data: [{"id":3,"date":"2015-06-19","views":49},{"id":2,"date":"2015-06-18","views":103},{"id":1,"date":"2015-06-17","views":18}],
    xkey: 'cron_time',
    ykeys: ['Page Views'],
    labels: ['Page Views'],
    lineColors: ['#0b62a4'],
    xLabels: 'Date',
    smooth: true,
    resize: true
});
```

without the rendering it looks like:

```
<div id="morris-line-chart">
    <?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=**********;charset=utf8', '*********', '********'); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pageviews ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <script>
        Morris.Line({
            element: 'morris-line-chart',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($row);?>,
            xkey: 'cron_time',
            ykeys: ['Page Views'],
            labels: ['Page Views'],
            lineColors: ['#0b62a4'],
            xLabels: 'Date',
            smooth: true,
            resize: true
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I was not sure exactly where to put the php and , when I copied the code into here I had it between the  tags but I have placed it above and below as well to try and rule out other possibilities. Is there anything you see that can help me get this working. I feel as though I am close but I can't quite find the last few errors. I am trying to provide as much code and detail as possible, if there is something you'd like to see that I am forgetting please let me know.

***EDIT:

I fixed the issue, I needed to change my xkey and ykey for it to work, all works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change xkey to date as it relates to the json array and also change the ykeys, placement goes after the